# VS Code default JS formatter not removing empty spaces

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How to make VS Code default JS formatter to remove empty white spaces?

I want the following code:

```
function Greetings()
{
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;




}
```

to look like:

```
function Greetings()
{
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to install the extension of [Prettier - Code formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), and set it as the default formatter of javascript?

```
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

A few extensions can do this such as Prettier 、Eslint、Vetur and so on. You can download it according to the function you want, and then set them in `settings.json`. You can modify it during the usage of the extension you have inatalled. Besides, you can also do some change accroding to this :[enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_formatting)

Comment: You should add an example of this `settings.json`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).